# How can I substitute/replace numbers inside a string as a multiplier for the letter inside the string?

Tags: javascript

For example: m1 = m , m2 = mm, m3i2 = mmmii

I am trying to find a simple way to do this. Any useful methods?

This is not a homework problem. I am just practicing on my Javascript skills.

Comment: Loop through the string and construct the output. It's not that complicated. Please explain what specifically you are having trouble with.

Comment: Regex wont help me understand the basics. I want to learn solving it through iterating. Can I separate the numbers and letters and then modify the string?

Answer (score 1):

So easy with regex and [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
function f(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.)(\d+)/g, (_, s, n) => s.repeat(n));
}
console.log(f('m1'));   // 'm'
console.log(f('m2'));   // 'mm'
console.log(f('m3i2')); // 'mmmii'
```

It can behave a bit inconsistent if the string starts with a digit. You may prefer `/(\D?)(\d+)/g`.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and use the result for returning the string

```js
var s = 'm3i2'.split(/(?=[a-z])/),
    result = s.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var i = +a.slice(1);
        while (i--) {
           r += a[0];
        }
        return r;
    }, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here in lambda style

```
"m2s3".split("").reduce((s,c) => isNaN(c) ? s + c : s + s[s.length-1].repeat(c-1));
```

> mmsss

Answer (score 0):

ES5 Example:

```
var s = 'm3i2j1';
var re = /([a-z])(\d+)/g;
var matches;
var buffer = [];
while (matches = re.exec(s)) {
  buffer.push(Array(+matches[2] + 1).join(matches[1]));
}
var output = buffer.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceNumbers(text) {
     var match = text.match(/\D\d*/g), ans = '', i, n;

     for (i = 0; i < match.length; ++i) {
          n = Number(match[i].substr(1));
          ans += match[i].substr(0, 1).repeat(n > 0 ? n : 1);
     }

     return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here is the solution I came up with.

function letTheNumberDoTheTalking(str) {
  var word = '';
  var start = 0;

  for (var next = 1; next < str.length; next += 2) {
    var letter = str[start];
    var multipliedLetter = str[start].repeat(str[next]);
    word += multipliedLetter;
    start = next + 1;
  }
  return word;
}

letTheNumberDoTheTalking('m1i1s2i1s2i1p2i1')); //==> 'mississippi'
```